# GCHQ puzzle, what is wrong?

Tags: prolog, puzzle, clpfd

I have tried to do this puzzle for fun:

http://qz.com/570665/can-you-solve-the-british-spy-agencys-ridiculously-difficult-christmas-puzzle/

I have 1's for black squares and 0s for white squares.

I query  ?- solve(Lists), append(Lists, Vars), label(Vars), maplist(writeln, Lists).

The answers I get back do not match the constraints of the puzzle.

```
 :-use_module(library(clpfd)).
 %hopefully there are typos here! This has been copied by hand.

 puzzle(RowLengths,ColLengths,BlackCoords):-
  ColLengths =[
  col(1, [7,2,1,1,7]),
  col(2, [1,1,2,2,1,1]),
  col(3, [1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1]),
  col(4, [1,3,1,1,5,1,3,1]),
  col(5, [1,3,1,1,4,1,3,1]),
  col(6, [1,1,1,2,1,1]),
  col(7, [7,1,1,1,1,1,7]),
  col(8, [1,1,3]),
  col(9, [2,1,2,1,8,2,1]),
  col(10,[2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2]),
  col(11,[1,7,3,2,1]),
  col(12,[1,2,3,1,1,1,1]),
  col(13,[4,1,1,2,6]),
  col(14,[3,1,1,1,3,1]),
  col(15,[1,2,5,2,2]),
  col(16,[2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1]),
  col(17,[1,3,3,2,1,8,1]),
  col(18,[6,2,1]),
  col(19,[7,1,4,1,1,3]),
  col(20,[1,1,1,1,4]),
  col(21,[1,3,1,3,7,1]),
  col(22,[1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,4]),
  col(23,[1,3,1,4,3,3]),
  col(24,[1,1,2,2,2,6,1]),
  col(25,[7,1,3,2,1,1])
  ],
 RowLengths=[
  row(1, [7,3,1,1,7]),
  row(2, [1,1,2,2,1,1]),
  row(3, [1,3,1,3,1,1,3,1]),
  row(4, [1,3,1,1,6,1,3,1]),
  row(5, [1,3,1,5,2,1,3,1]),
  row(6, [1,1,2,1,1]),
  row(7, [7,1,1,1,1,1,7]),
  row(8, [3,3]),
  row(9, [1,2,3,1,1,3,1,1,2]),
  row(10,[1,1,3,2,1,1]),
  row(11,[4,1,4,2,1,2]),
  row(12,[1,1,1,1,1,4,1,3]),
  row(13,[2,1,1,1,2,5]),
  row(14,[3,2,2,6,3,1]),
  row(15,[1,9,1,1,2,1]),
  row(16,[2,1,2,2,3,1]),
  row(17,[3,1,1,1,1,5,1]),
  row(18,[1,2,2,5]),
  row(19,[7,1,2,1,1,1,3]),
  row(20,[1,1,2,1,2,2,1]),
  row(21,[1,3,1,4,5,1]),
  row(22,[1,3,1,3,10,2]),
  row(23,[1,3,1,1,6,6]),
  row(24,[1,1,2,1,1,2]),
  row(25,[7,2,1,2,5])
 ],
 BlackCoords= [
   [4,4],[5,4], [13,4],[14,4],[22,4],
   [7,9],[8,9],[11,9],[15,9],[16,9],[19,9],
   [7,17],[12,17],[17,17],[21,17],
   [4,22],[5,22],[10,22],[11,22],[16,22],[21,22],[22,22]
 ].
%This is meant to set each index value from blacks in list to one
list_of_blacks(List,Blacks):-
  length(Blacks,NumberOfBlacks),
  length(NumberOfOnesList,NumberOfBlacks),
  NumberOfOnesList ins 1..1,
  maplist(my_nth1(List),Blacks,NumberOfOnesList).

%This is meant to take a row or column and set the values to one, which are needed to meet the constraint for that row or col
row(List,LengthsOfBlacks):-
 maplist(my_length,LengthsOfBlacks,BlackLists),
 splitlistIf(=(1),List,BlackLists).

x_cords(Xs):-
  puzzle(_,_,BlackCords),
  length(BlackCords,Len),
  length(Xs,Len),
  maplist(nth1(1),BlackCords,Xs).

y_cords(Ys):-
  puzzle(_,_,BlackCords),
  length(BlackCords,Len),
  length(Ys,Len),
  maplist(nth1(2),BlackCords,Ys).

solve(Puzzle):-
  generate_matrix(25,25,Puzzle),
  flatten(Puzzle,Flat),
  Flat ins 0..1,
  x_cords(XCords),
  y_cords(YCords),
  maplist(my_set(Puzzle),XCords,YCords),
  puzzle(RowLengths,ColLengths,_),
  maplist(remove_row,RowLengths,RowBlacks),
  maplist(remove_col,ColLengths,ColBlacks),
  maplist(row,Puzzle,RowBlacks),
  transpose(Puzzle,PuzzleT),
  maplist(row,PuzzleT,ColBlacks).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%helpers

my_nth1(List,Index,El):-
 nth1(Index,List,El).

my_length(Len,List):-
 length(List,Len).

generate_matrix(Cols, Rows, Matrix) :-
 my_length(Rows, Matrix),
 maplist(my_length(Cols), Matrix).

remove_row(X,Y):-
 X=row(_,Y).

remove_col(X,Y):-
 X=col(_,Y).

my_set(M,Row,Col) :-
 nth1(Row,M,RowList),
 nth1(Col,RowList,1).

%%%Other preds from stack overflow
 if_(If_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
  call(If_1, T),
  (  T == true -> call(Then_0)
  ;  T == false -> call(Else_0)
  ;  nonvar(T) -> throw(error(type_error(boolean,T),_))
  ;  /* var(T) */ throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
 ).

=(X, Y, T) :-
 (  X == Y -> T = true
 ;  X \= Y -> T = false
 ;  T = true, X = Y
 ;  T = false,
   dif(X, Y)                             % ISO extension
   % throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) % ISO strict
 ).


equal_t(X, Y, T) :-
 =(X, Y, T).
split_if(P_2,As,Bss) :- splitlistIf(P_2,As,Bss).

splitlistIf(P_2,As,Bss) :-
 list_pred_split(As,P_2,Bss).

list_pred_split([],_,[]).
list_pred_split([X|Xs],P_2,Bss) :-
  if_(call(P_2,X), list_pred_split(Xs,P_2,Bss),
                 (Bss = [[X|Ys]|Bss0],     list_pred_open_split(Xs,P_2,Ys,Bss0))).

list_pred_open_split([],_,[],[]).
list_pred_open_split([X|Xs],P_2,Ys,Bss) :-
 if_(call(P_2,X), (Ys = [],      list_pred_split(Xs,P_2,Bss)),
                (Ys = [X|Ys0], list_pred_open_split(Xs,P_2,Ys0,Bss))).
```

Comment: Sorry I was labeling the results, but it is not correct.

The results do not match what they should be, so some of the logic is wrong..

Comment: "Not correct" can mean three things: Either the program is only too general, or it is only too specific, or it is both too general and too specific. Which is it? Does it yield solutions that you want to exclude? Does it *not* yield solutions you are expecting? Or both?

Comment: I have added an example solution that it finds. You can see that the top row is all ones, but it should have 7 blacks a white, then 3 blacks, then one black, a space, then another black, then 7 further blacks. so it should have 19 ones in total.

Comment: Just as you hoped, quite a few of the row hints and column hints in the model are wrong. For the correct hints, see for example my Picat model (using CP solver): http://hakank.org/picat/nonogram_gchq.pi   The problem has one unique solution with the 22 black hints (and 4 solutions without).